# Form validation for dynamically added fields in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, validation

I have created a form in react which has 2 fields. After clicking add button it adds same 2 more fields. Now I want to validate those fields. Can anyone help me please.

Codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-form-fields-9fzzh

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little incomplete. First, tell me which field you want to validate and what you have tried till now. For reference you can check this site:[here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/up-and-running-with-react-form-validation)

Comment: Forget about it, i got the solution. I have updated code in the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. The standard up until recently has been using a large yup schema with conditional validation (using 'when').

I made a library called *Fielder* specifically for dynamic field-level validation such as in your example. It prevents the need to use a large schema and provide conditions up front.

Check out the second two [examples on this page](https://fielder.andyrichardson.dev/examples) which dynamically add validation criteria as the user progresses through the form.

Check out the [Fielder repo](https://github.com/andyrichardson/fielder) and let me know if it works out for you!